# How to get different autorotation function in different UIViewController in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, autorotate

I am working on the application in which i only want to enable landscape mode for one UIViewController. rest of the pages i want in portrait mode.

Its very easy in iOS upto 5 SDK with shouldautorotate method but in iOS 6 due to new rotation methods, "supportedInterfaceOrientations" does not seems to provide this feature easily either i can enable rotation in all views or can fix to one mode only.